# Different Resource Representations (REST API)

Tags: rest

I'm developing a REST API and I have a question about resource representations.

Suppose I have the "person" resource under the `/app/person/{id}` URI. I need an XML representation, that basically is all the object fields as XML nodes under the  root. Now, requirements indicate that we must also support another kind of XML representation enforced by a proprietary schema.

My question: is it in accordance with REST best practices to support a proprietary content type like `text/my-type` for the same resource? Note that both are XML but formatted differently, and most importantly they don't carry the same information (e.g. one representation may include other fields like `modified-since`).

Important! - I know that being pragmatic and keeping it simple is more important than guides and "best practices" but I just wanted to know if this is the way to go under a RESTful architecture.

Comment: If you are specifying a URI naming scheme in your API (like  /app/person/{id}) then your API is RPC, not REST.

Comment: @Wahnfrieden
Could you explain why a URI naming scheme means RPC. I disagree with you. /app/person/{id} is a reference to a person resource. The URI does nothing except illustrates where the person resource can be found, which is perfectly RESTful. An RPC URI would be something like /app/dancing/dothefunkychicken?personid={id} as you are using the URI to invoke an action.

Comment: @pablo Yes @Wahnfrieden does know what REST is.  The problem is that many people are trying to define REST API's like they define RPC APIs, by defining a set of endpoints. REST APIs don't work this way.  REST API design should be focused on the definition of the media types.  What the endpoints are is completely irrelevant to the client and the RESTfulness of the API.  However, the server implementation does care about the URLs, so it is difficult to get people to ignore them whilst doing the design.

Comment: @Benedict If you are designing your interface around a set of URIs there is a reasonable probability that you are going to build a client application with implicit knowledge of that URL structure.  At that point you might as well be doing RPC because you are not taking advantage of the benefits of REST.

Comment: Ok. I was wrong and I'm sorry for that... but are you (Darrel) suggesting that the client SHOULD NOT KNOW the URL structure??

Comment: @Darrel I'm not saying that all URI's for a service must be pre-defined. All I'm saying is that /app/person/{id} is a perfectly RESTful URI. 

I agree that it should be possible to discover all of the resource that a service makes available by following links permeating from the root URI of the service. However, having a well organized URI naming scheme such as /app/people/ , /app/locations/ , /app/furniture/ does not mean a service is un-RESTful. I'd argue that such a name scheme is incredible useful as it helps people that use the service understand the data model of the service.

Comment: @Benedict REST specifies nothing about URI naming except that URIs must be opaque. /app/person/{id} might as well be /app/{8926893,34568,dsf324} for all it cares. You shouldn't encourage understanding of your service's structures through URIs, because it can easily lead to clients depending on URI structure. Your service should be easy enough to understand purely through its hypertext and media types. URI structures don't always map accurately to hypertext relationships anyway, so it can just be confusing. That's why we get so many questions here about how to organize URI space.

Comment: @Pablo correct, URIs should be completely opaque to clients.

Comment: @Wahnfrieden. I see your point, and it has some merit. However, I still don't agree. [I'm now going to pull a cheap trick and refer to a higher authority] Roy Fielding says: "REST does not require that a URI be opaque. The only place where the word opaque occurs in my dissertation is where I complain about the opaqueness of cookies. In fact, RESTful applications are, at all times, encouraged to use human-meaningful, hierarchical identifiers in order to maximize the serendipitous use of the information beyond what is anticipated by the original application."

Comment: @Benedict  You are correct.  Roy has said that he has no problem with humans being able to guess at valid urls. However, he also said "A REST API must not define fixed resource names or hierarchies (an obvious coupling of client and server)".  The client application cannot have the server URLs coded into it.  "Servers must have the freedom to control their own namespace."

Comment: @Pablo  Correct.  The client should not know the url structure.  As an exercise, next time you want to build a REST interface, do it like you do TDD.  Create the client first and use a stub for the server. Make the client get the URLs from the retrieved representations.  You will quickly see that the client does not care what the urls look like.  Now go and implement the real server using whatever url structure is the easiest.  The client code should not change.

Comment: @Benedict Thanks for the quote. That's good to know. But the client code still should not have any coupling to URI structure. @Darrel That's a great way to approach building RESTful services, thanks.

Comment: @Darrell I still fail to see how to code a client without knowing the URL's of the API. Could you please point me to a more complete reference/article of what you are saying? I've read "RESTful Webservices" and It didn't said anything about "opaque urls"

Comment: @Pablo. The client should only know the entry point to the service, EG music/. The resource at music/ should provide a representation that allows for all other resources to be discovered directly or indirectly, EG XML containing metadata and links to the other resources. The client can then parse the XML to find the URIs for the other resources. Therefore the client doesn't have to know the URI structure before using the service. However, "doesn't have to" isn't the same as "shouldn't". A good URI aids human users by adding semantic meaning.

Comment: @Benedict the client still should not understand the URI structure - even if it is human readable. (just to be clear)

Comment: @Pablo  I wish there were some good examples of implementing REST clients to point you to.  Maybe one day I will get around to trying to write one. Until then, think about how a web browser is able to allow you do so much on a web site that it knows _nothing_ about.

Comment: Ok guys thanks for the insight... I think it makes sense somehow, the client would be "navigating" or "browsing" the services (and I don't know if they can be called services up to this point, but resources). Definitely the comments were a lot more interesting than the original question. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.  There are no REST constraints that prevent you from returning two different representations of a resource from the same URL.  Even, if one media type is a proprietary format.  Be careful about allowing the content to vary too much, I hear that some people get pretty upset about that.
Also, for the custom formats you should use a media type under the vendor subtree

e.g. application/vnd.companyname.format+xml

However, it is not really in the spirit of REST to return proprietary formats.  That being said, you can do with without any problems other than limiting serendipitous re-use.

Comment: REST has no issues with proprietary formats - HATEOS actually describes this scenario perfectly.  A client who wants to interact with a RESTful service need only know the media types returned by that service (whether they be jpeg, Atom XML, Word docs, etc...)

Answer (score 5):

If the second format is simply a different syntax (or can reasonably be viewed as such), it's perfectly fine (and RESTful and in compliance with REST best practices) to add it as a second representation with another media type. If you consider the difference to be more than syntactical, you should probably create a different resource. The same is true if you want to be able to link to a specific representation (because it needs a different URI if you want to do so). In this latter case, you might want to consider a canonical, format-independent resource as well that can return a 303 See Other with links to the specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

If these are just two different representations of a Person resource, then you ought to have two media types for them.  If at all possible try to find and reuse standard representations and their media types (see http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).  Both media types should have the form `application/`*type*`+xml` (and see Darrel's comment).

Comment: Custom types based on xml are named application/type+xml.  If you are creating your own custom type then usually they are created under the vendor subtree. e.g. application/vnd.mycompany.mytype+xml

Comment: Thanks Jim, link is broken though

Comment: @Darrel I was wondering why xml doesn't come before the vendor tree - application/xml+vnd.mycompany.mytype ? Then clients which handle any type of XML, even just a simple XML prettifier, could easily see that it is an application media type, and using XML, and then it further specializes into a vendor specific space. This makes more sense to me, unless the content-type specifications instruct clients to ignore what comes between the / and + if they don't care about vendor specific specializations or something wacky like that.

Answer (score 1):

Content Negotiation is built into HTTP using the Accept and Accept-Encoding headers.  The client apps should specify what type they want returned by setting these headers.

Comment: This does not answer what I asked... seems like a comment more than an answer

Comment: What he means by this comment is that the HTTP protocol has powerful, built-in capabilities to handle returning multiple representations from the same resource.